# Is there an official statement about Detective Conan's ending?

Tags: detective-conan

Currently, Detective Conan series is now on it's 721 ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Case_Closed_episodes_%28seasons_16%E2%80%93current%29#Season_23%3a_2013.E2.80.932014)) and probably still counting. Is there any statement from the production if they have any plans on having this anime series end? If there is, what is their plan on doing so? Will Conan be able to revert back to Shinichi and have the Black Organization behind bars or something like that? Or do they want this to be open-ended?

Comment: Nothing has been put about about this lately. All your questions can probably be answered by the mangaka himself. As far as anime is concerned, its going pretty well so i don't think they'll stop it. The manga is about a 100 chapters ahead of episode 721!!
So its kind of difficult to tell.

Comment: neither the anime nor manga seems like it's headed towards a conclusion any time soon...

Answer (score 6):

There hasn't been any official announcement related to the end of the manga or the anime, but here's an interview with [Aoyama Gosho](http://detective-conan-news.blogspot.ca/2011/05/2011-aoyama-gosho-interview.html) which took place in 2011.

> I really didn't expect it to last this long. I thought it might end after the first volume. Also, about the name "Conan," initially the editor-in-chief told me to change it to Detective Doyle because there was already an anime called Conan, The Boy in Future (directed by Miyazaki Hayao), but I said “I'd overtake The Boy in Future!” and it finally got through. But the new serialization's announcement said Tantei Shonen Conan/Detective Boy Conan, and I thought no way, this is pretty bad (laughs). However, about 10 years ago, someone from Ghibli* said to me, “when you talk about Conan now you'd be referring to the detective,” and I thought “Yes, I did it!”

This should clear most of your questions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer any of my questions though.

Comment: I agree, neither the quote nor the link itself gives any indication that he plans on stopping the manga anytime soon.